# Get text until first <br />

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery, but am a bit stumped with this one. I have the following HTML:

```
...
<h1 class="myClass">First Part<br />Second Part</h1>
...
```

I can isolate this element from downloaded data using:

```
$(data).find("h1.myClass");
```

What I want to extract is the "First Part" bit. I assumed I could do this:

```
$(data).find("h1.myClass:first-child").text();
```

However, this results in an empty string. After doing a lot of searching, I am still unsure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, all! Your solutions all seem to work, and I'll definitely be doing a little more research on each of them to understand better why they work and mine didn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>`$(".myClass").text().split("<br />")[0];`</strike>

#### EDIT:

```
$(".myClass").html().split("<br />")[0];
```

Referrence correction comment: @box9

Comment: I think you want `.html()` instead. jQuery's `.text()` will strip all HTML tags.

Answer (score 5):

Using just plain old JavaScript and DOM, once you have the H1 dom object you can just call `myH1.firstChild` and that will return the text node up to the next element (on which you can call "data" to get the text string).  For example:

```
<h1 class="myClass">This is<br/>a test</h1>
//...
var hs = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
hs[0].firstChild.data; // => "This is"
```

Or with idiomatic jQuery:

```
$("h1.myClass").get(0).firstChild.data; // => "This is"
```

Don't forget that jQuery is powerful and often super-duper-time-saving but the DOM itself provides some good functionality as well.

Comment: I think the OP wants it in jQuery :)

Answer (score 5):

To get a little more 'jQuery-ish':

```
$("h1.myClass").contents().eq(0).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

why not using some regexp to do so

```
var content = $(data).find("h1.myClass:first-child").html();
var filteredContent = /(.*)<br \/>/.exec(content)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

"First Part" isn't a child as it isn't in its own element.

You could get the First Part by splitting the contents of `<h1 class="myClass">` by the `<br />`:

```
var firstPart = $("h1.myClass").html().split('<br />')[0];

alert(firstPart);
```

^ that will alert "First Part" :)